# is there any possible conflict for fields with the same machine name?

Tags: paragraphs, entities

i am trying to debug a paragraph not displaying fields and i am having

> /admin/reports/fields

a same machine name for a field in 3 different paragraphs

```
field_call_to_action_ref    paragraph   Entity reference revisions (module : entity_reference_revisions)    

    Bloc compositeParagraphe standardElement d'accordéon
```

Comment: This is no problem, as long as the field is of the same type and it is OK for you that they share the same field storage having all the same basic field settings, restricting you to change only settings which are stored in the content type like the field label and form/display settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Machine names for fields must be unique per entity type.

The means that with nodes, fields must be unique across all content types. So you can't create two fields with the same machine name on different content types, as both content types are nodes, and machine names must be unique for the entity type. (Edit - you can however re-use the same field on multiple content types, but it will be the same field, not two fields with the same machine name).

You can have a `field_image` on a node, and `field_image` on a taxonomy term. Here, the machine name is the same, but unique to each entity type, so there is no problem.